# How to create a new entry in a specific collection?

Tags: graphql, strapi

Or in other words: How can I create a new entry that has a relationship with a specific collection and only with it?

The following code creates a new entry of the type Brand. How can I place it inside a specific collection?

I'm new to graphql, so if what I would like to achieve is not possible at all or not the way graphql works please tell me

Additional information:
I'm using mlab as my back end, and strapi (headless cms). On strapi I installed graphql as an external plugin.

Thanks in advance

```
mutation {
  createBrand(input: {
    data: {
      name: "John",
      description: "this is my description"
    }
  }) {
    brand {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: GraphQL itself is agnostic to the underlying data layer. Is this question related to `prisma`, `graphcool` or some other tool built on top of GraphQL?

Comment: As it stands, there's not enough detail in this question to provide a meaningful answer. Please edit the question to add information about what endpoint you are querying. If this is a server you are running yourself, we would need to see the relevant server-side code. If the server is using something like `prisma`, that would be relevant information as well. If you're querying some existing public API, please indicate which one.

Comment: Hey Daniel alrright I'm editing it now to add this. I thought it was more of a question about understanding basic concepts here

Answer (score 1):

To my very limited understanding of graphql, I think that in order to associate a new entry with a specific collection you need to edit the code above and add:

```
mutation {
  createBrand(input: {
    data: {
      name: "John",
      description: "this is my description"
      collectionInPlurals: ['collectionId']
    }
  }) {
    brand {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

collectioninPlurals for example could be items if the type of the collection is 'item' and then you provide the id of the specific item

I hope it could benefit others...